# How to call a php variable in .js file?

Tags: javascript, php

I want to use a php variable in .js file. Is this possible that we can call a php variable in .js file.
what I have done for this problem

I have .php file where i created var

```
$domainname = "wwww.google.com ";
```

In second file .php

```
<?php  header("Content-type: application/javascript"); ?>
<script> 
var DomainName = <?php echo $GLOBALS['SettingDomainName'];?> 
</script>
```

and finally I want to call this var in js

```
<script src="public_https/test.js"></script>
alert(DomainName);
```

I got this message :

```
SyntaxError: syntax error
<script src="public_https/test.js"></script>
```

Comment: does var DomainName = <?php echo $GLOBALS['SettingDomainName'];?>; (added a semicolumn after the php close tag) helps?

Comment: You dont need to wrap that into `script` tag and you should make it a string.

Comment: @Goikiu did you see that funny picture where morphius says that semicolons are optional on javascript?

Answer (score 3):

Use [**`json_encode`**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) function which returns JSON representation of a variable which can be used inside JavaScript as-is:

```
<?php
$domainname = "www.google.com";
?>
<script>
var DomainName = <?php echo json_encode($domainname); ?>;
</script>
```

Note: no quotes. This function works for all types of variable: string, integer, float, boolean, null and etc.

Comment: Sorry, my bad. You're completely right.

Answer (score 0):

```
<script> 
var DomainName = "<?php echo $GLOBALS['SettingDomainName'];?>";
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<input type="hidden" id="domain_name" value="<?php echo $GLOBALS['SettingDomainName']; ?>">
```

JsFile:

```
var DomainName= document.getElementById('domain_name');
```

Comment: You might want to elaborate on what your answer does. SO exists to teach, not just answer questions. You also need to wrap that `echo` statement in `<?php ?>`

Comment: @machavity Hi, Updated the answer pls check review it

Comment: Better from a code standpoint but still needs some comments on what this does. Compare your answer to the one Salman gave. He talks about his answer some.

Comment: @machavity okay, I will try to improve :)

Answer (score 0):

What about we hide your variable in a hidden box using php

```
 $domainname = "wwww.google.com ";

<input type="hidden" value=" <?php  echo "$domainname"; ?>" id="mydomain">
```

Then we fetch it using js or jquery

```
<script>
     var domain=$('#mydomain').val();
</script>
```